# Refactoring without losing history - TortoiseHG

Tags: version-control, tortoisehg

I've done some refactoring which resulted in that some of the content of my original file is split into several other files. However I don't want to lose the history of the code that was moved to the other files but I can't seem to find a way to achieve this in Tortoisehg. What would be my best strategy to keep the code history? Is this even possible or do I need to use the original file for history of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use console, `hg copy` in the middle. Or fix mistake with `-A` option (did not try)

**Sample for easy case**

```
>hg log
2015-01-13 23:48 +0500  fd3ee8f03c54 [tip]

        * fileA.txt, fileB.txt: new file.
        * file.txt: deleted file.
        * file.txt, fileA.txt, fileB.txt:
        Refactoring

2015-01-13 23:44 +0500  0c2bb611605a

        * .hgignore, file.txt: new file.
        * .hgignore, file.txt:
        Initial state
```

I.e.: `file.txt` was commited in initial changeset, later was separated to `fileA.txt` and `fileB.txt` and removed

Before fd3ee8f03c54 I recorded copy for Mercurial with

```
>hg cp file.txt fileA.txt
>hg cp file.txt fileB.txt
```

and log for single file, used with `-f` option, now knows about file ancestor

```
>hg log -f fileA.txt -T "changeset:\t{rev}:{node|short}\n"
changeset:      1:fd3ee8f03c54
changeset:      0:0c2bb611605a

>hg log -f fileB.txt -T "changeset:\t{rev}:{node|short}\n"
changeset:      1:fd3ee8f03c54
changeset:      0:0c2bb611605a
```

or, in TortoiseHG they also can be diff'ed

[image: Log]

Comment: Thank's a lot, will prove very useful. I had a really hard time finding information about this, a task that seems like it would be rather common, do people generally not care about maintaining the history or is it a lot easier to perform this in for example Git?